# Check Is the array is empty in one line

Tags: java, arrays

I have been asked recently to check if an array is empty or not in one line of code.

My thought was to use `array.length==0`. But if the array is initialized like this,

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

This will have array of size 5 and has '0' in every index.

Can you please help me to find a one line code to check is it empty or not?

Comment: define 'empty'. Since it has values, it isn't empty.

Comment: What do you mean by empty? Do you mean if it's `null`?

Comment: @Maljam it can't contain null values, since int's aren't objects

Comment: @Stultuske I meant if `array == null`

Comment: @Maljam then there is no array. that's not the same as being empty.

Comment: @Stultuske that's why we are asking him to define "empty"...

Comment: @Maljam yes, but we already know (s)he is not looking for a null-check, since "the array is instantiated as new int[5]"

Comment: @Stultuske but he doesn't say if he considers `new int[5]` to be empty or not

Comment: As stated by others, it depends on the array and what you define as empty. If you use an int-array (or any other primitive array) like in your example, the array is never empty (unless you have `new int[0];`) since they'll have `0` as default value. If you have an array of Objects or Strings or something similar however, the array could be "empty" if you define all objects that are null (which is the default for Objects) as empty. So, as _Stultuske_ asked, define 'empty' with the `int[] array = new int[5];` given, please.

Answer (score 4):

If you are wanting to check if array contains any non-zero element you can use streams for one line decision:

```
Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch(x -> x != 0);
```

But it can produce NullPointerException, if you are wanting to avoid it you can use `Optional`:

```
Arrays.stream(Optional.ofNullable(array).orElse(new int[0])).anyMatch(x -> x != 0))
```

Comment: When will we be able to stop qualifying things as Java 8? I don't see everyone warning about generics...

Answer (score 2):

- If you define empty as an array which has ***zero elements***, you can check if it is empty by using the following condition:

  ```
  if (array.length == 0)
  ```

  You will find it empty only if you have initialized your array as `int[] array = new int[0];`.
- If you want to check if your array is ***null***, use :

  ```
  if (arr == null)
  ```
- If you define empty as ***having no values different that zero*** , the condition :

  ```
  Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch(element -> element != 0);
  ```

  will check if your any of the array's elements is different than zero.
- You can also use the method `ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(array)` from the package `org.apache.commons.lang3` which ensures that your array is ***neither null nor empty***.